# Installation error for CNTK v2beta15

Tags: windows, installation, neural-network, lstm, cntk

I am trying to run my model on Philly cluster which uses CNTK v2beta15 with py34. Could someone point me to the documentation for that particular version as many commands and examples of CNTK v2.0 (stable) are not working on Philly. Also, I am running into issues while installing the v2beta15 locally. I downloaded the binaries and trying to run install.bat while the machine crashes.
Any solution would be very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Python documentation for 2.0b15 is at
https://cntk.ai/pythondocs-ver/2_0-beta15/

Also, consider rephrasing your question to benefit other SO users. Is the Philly cluster something that the rest of the community should care about? If you have issues with internal infrastructure in your organization it might be best to contact the team responsible for that through non-public means.